# Is this sentence grammatically correct ? Can 'a / an' follows 'are'?

Tags: grammar

Can someone help me understand what's happening here? I don't think I have seen this before, thank you so much!

"The takeaway is clear: cats ***are a*** growing environmental concern because they are driving down some native bird populations."

Comment: I see no reason at all to question that structure.

Comment: Concern is one, and cats are many. Both are in stock at JCPenny.